# How to publish a few snippets in a single file Sublime Text 3?

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext3

How to publish a few snippets in a single file Sublime Text 3?

I am use this code, but do not work. I have error!

```
<snippets>
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
.............................
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>span</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>span</description>
</snippet>

<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
.............................
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>img</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>img</description>
</snippet>

</snippets>
```

Answer (score 4):

For multiple snippets, you'll need to either make multiple `.sublime-snippet` files, or set up a custom [completions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html) list. Yours might look something like this:

```json
{
    "scope": "text.html - source, punctuation.definition.tag.begin",

    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "myspan", "contents": "<span class=\"$1\" id=\"$2\">$0</span>" },
        { "trigger": "myimg", "contents": "<img alt=\"$1\" src=\"$2\" class=\"$3\" id=\"$4\" />$0" },
    ]
}
```

Save it in your `Packages/User` directory as `HTML.sublime-completions` (you can access `Packages` by going to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`). Now, when you're coding and type `span` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up autocomplete (if it doesn't appear automatically, you'll see the following:

[image: span autocomplete]

The top option is Sublime's built-in completion, which just gives `<span>|</span>` where `|` is the cursor. I have the [Tag](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Tag) package installed, so it adds another option that basically does the same thing as Sublime's. The third option is our new completion. You'll need to arrow down to select your completion, but the good news is that the next time you type `span` it'll be selected, so you can just hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and go on to fill in the options.

I hope this helps, please let me know if you have any questions.